# RabbitMQ installation on Mac

Tags: macos, rabbitmq

Sorry for this noob-questions. [Here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-standalone-mac.html) written:

> Contained in the tarball is a directory named rabbitmq_server-3.3.5.
>   You should extract this into somewhere appropriate for application
>   binaries on your system.

Where it is? **sbin**, **usr/bin**, **bin** or something else? So, every time on startup I need to go to that path and command:

```
sbin/rabbitmq-server -detach
```

Or I can do it like this:

```
rabbitmq-server -detach
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just [brew](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-homebrew.html) it?

Comment: Apart from just using homebrew, whenever you want a script to be invoked like that, the folder of the script should be in your path. Otherwise add an alias of said script into a folder that's on your path.